# Ndepend Error no is no application assembly defined in the project

Tags: build, ndepend

I'm trying to analyze VS solution via Ndepend as part of a tfs build.
I added an .ndproj file in the same directory of .sln file under Sources folder.
I'm Using Team Build 2010 workflow activity to add Ndepend as part of the build.
But I encountred this problem :
  **There is no application assembly defined in the project file**
Can any one help me please.

Comment: Asma, could you be explicit about how you are creating your NDepend project? Are you doing it manually? Are you doing it through NDepend.API?

Comment: I used Visual ndepend to create ndepend project.

Comment: Did you check that assemblies files exists on the TFS machine? Does VisualNDepend > Project Properties > Code to Analyze panel find assemblies in the TFS machine? Are you using the last 5.1 version released 2 weeks ago that fixes a bug that could explain such a problem?

Comment: I'm using The newes Ndepend 5.1. For assemblies, Yes it  exists in binairies folder.

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your help, I verified the project properties and   there was no assembly. I added the Assemblies to analyse and now it works fine. Thank you very much.

Comment: You are welcome Asma!